# How do I resolve this error when I open Jupyter notbook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryAHy.jpg)

```
(base) grantmeadowsjr@Grants-Mac ~ % jupyter lab
[I 2021-11-27 10:33:53.031 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2021-11-27 10:33:53.429 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully linked.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-lab", line 10, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_server/extension/application.py", line 510, in launch_instance
serverapp = cls.initialize_server(argv=args)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_server/extension/application.py", line 479, in initialize_server
serverapp.initialize(
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 88, in inner
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_server/serverapp.py", line 1831, in initialize
self.init_httpserver()
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_server/serverapp.py", line 1752, in init_httpserver
self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 151, in listen
sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 161, in bind_sockets
sock.bind(sockaddr)
OSError: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address
```

This is the error I receive when I open jupyter notebook from anaconda. I am not very familiar with using the mac terminal, I had to download anaconda for my class.

Comment: don't post screenshots. post the text

Comment: could you try doing this? ```jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8080``` let me know what happens

Comment: jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8080     , this worked. It opened the jupyter notebook. Thank you very much.